# Why does JAX-WS freeze while deploying any service using JAXB databinding?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I'm attempting to create a JAX-WS service that uses JAXB databinding of objects generated from the very large (900+ classes) set of [Opentravel Alliance schemas](http://www.opentravel.org/specifications/SchemaIndex.aspx?FolderName=2011B).

I am able to successfully deploy a war (with proper web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml) containing my JAX-WS service on various servlet containers (Jetty, Tomcat6/7, etc.) as long as my web method does **not** reference any of my JAXB objects.  For example, this works:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "OTAService", 
targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
@Addressing
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class OTAService {
    public String sayHello(final String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

However, if I change the web method to use JAXB databinding by adding a `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation or by referencing the objects directly, all of the servlet containers I have tried hang indefinitely (1+ hours), without error, and never start:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "OTAService", 
targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
@Addressing
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({OTAHotelResNotifRQ.class, OTAHotelResNotifRS.class})
public class OTAService {
    @Action(input = "OTA_HotelResNotif")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "OTA_HotelResNotif", action = "OTA_HotelResNotif")
    public @WebResult OTAHotelResNotifRQ tokenizeOtaHotelResNotifRq(
    @WebParam(partName = "OTA_HotelResNotifRQ", name = "OTA_HotelResNotifRQ", 
    targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05") 
    final OTAHotelResNotifRQ request) {
        return request;
    }
}
```

I have verified that all of the necessary jars, including the JAXB and JAX-WS APIs and runtime jars, are present in the war's /lib directory.

The jar containing my JAXB objects, which is a required dependency for my JAX-WS project, can be created and installed to your local repo by running `mvn clean install` on [this project](https://github.com/justingarrick/opentravel-2011b-all).

My JAX-WS project, which is available [here](https://github.com/justingarrick/jaxws-test), can be run in Jetty by invoking `mvn clean package jetty:run-war`.

You will notice that Jetty starts right up if only the simple `sayHello` method is present.  However, if you uncomment the JAXB method, Jetty and every other servlet container that I've tried will hang forever while attempting to instantiate the  JAX-WS servlet.  **Can someone explain why web methods with JAXB databinding prevent my war from deploying?  Since the freezing behavior is identical on a variety of servlet containers, I feel that there must be some crucial step that I'm missing; however, since no errors are reported and the container startup just hangs, I do not know how to proceed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this was due to the large number of JAXB objects in my opentravel project.  When I connected VisualVM to the launcher process and sampled the memory, it looked as if JAXB was walking and preloading/caching the entire object tree for some reason (perhaps to reconstruct the schema for inclusion in the WSDL?).

Setting `-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.fastBoot=true` as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794354/jaxbcontext-initialization-speedup) and bumping up the memory with `-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` got Jetty to start up quickly.

I am not yet sure if the runtime performance hit will be an acceptable trade-off.